# Can't deploy Nestjs to Heroku

Tags: api, heroku, deployment, nestjs, backend

I'm trying to deploy a nestjs app to heroku but I get this error in the logs

```
2022-09-03T16:19:06.793730+00:00 app[web.1]: > pokedex@0.0.1 start:prod
2022-09-03T16:19:06.793731+00:00 app[web.1]: > node dist/main
2022-09-03T16:19:06.793731+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859243+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859244+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859245+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859245+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859245+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/main'
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859246+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859248+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859248+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: []
2022-09-03T16:19:06.859249+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I created a Procfile with npm run start:prod command, also tried moving `@nestjs/cli` devDependency to dependencies but it doesn't work

Comment: In your local directory, when you run `build` do you have `dist/main` as an output or `dist/src/main`?

Comment: My bad, main.js is located in dist/src/main after running build, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Next js goes perfectly with vercel if you are not bounded with a single option to deploy

Comment: [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com) is a Node framework built on top of Express or Fastify using OOP and decorators. Completely unrelated to react or NextJS. Confusing name, I know, but because of that, Vercel would not be an option

Answer (score 0):

The `start:prod` command in the `package.json` should be updated to read `"start:prod": "node dist/src/main"` due to how the project is built. Usually this means that there is a `ts` file outside of `src` that is being read as a part of the project, or some other import is happening to a file outside of the source root

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Nest.js build the main.js in dist/src/

I also created a Procfile with `web: npm run start:prod` to run the app